# Swift Comparing Elements of Two Separate Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

I am trying to compare the elements in two different arrays in Swift without using higher order functions. The function should return an array of integers that are in both arrays. I think I am close, but am getting 'an index out range error. Also would like to know how this measures on time complexity

```
let arrayOne = [1, 5, 12, 3, -15 , 52, 20]
let arrayTwo = [3, 1, 6, 5, 57, 13, 17, 20]

func compareElementsInArray(array1:[Int], array2: [Int]) -> [Int] {

let totalArray = array1 + array2
var sortedArray = totalArray.sorted()
var results = [Int]()

for i in totalArray {
    if sortedArray[i + 1] == sortedArray[i] {
        results.append(sortedArray[i])
    }
}

return results

}

compareElementsInArray(array1: arrayOne, array2: arrayTwo)
```

Comment: why did this question get downvoted??

Comment: `for i in totalArray { if sortedArray[i + 1] == sortedArray[i]...` `sortedArray.count == totalArray.count`, right? So if "i" is the last index, you can't do `totalArray[i+1]`, nor `sortedArray[i+1]`, that's why you are getting a index out of bounds issue. Also, your logic implies that there is no duplicate values inside `arrayOne` or inside `arrayTwo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating through all element of `totalArray` meaning that `i` will reach the last index of `totalArray`, then you are trying to access the `i+1`-th element of `sortedArray`, which has the same length as `totalArray`, hence the error.

You need to stop the loop at the index before the last one, not the last one.

```
func compareElementsInArray(array1:[Int], array2: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    let totalArray = array1 + array2
    var sortedArray = totalArray.sorted()
    var results = [Int]()

    for i in 0..<totalArray.count-1 {
        if sortedArray[i + 1] == sortedArray[i] {
            results.append(sortedArray[i])
        }
    }

    return results

}

print(compareElementsInArray(array1: arrayOne, array2: arrayTwo))
```

However, you can use an `NSCountedSet` to achieve the same using higher order functions (your solutions doesn't actually use higher order functions).

You just have to create a counted set from the combination of the arrays, then use `flatMap` to `filter` the elements whose count is greater than 1 and `map` the result to `[Int]`.

```
func nonUniqueElements(array1: [Int], array2: [Int])->[Int] {
    let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: array1+array2)
    return countedSet.flatMap({ element in
        if countedSet.count(for: element) > 1 {
            return element as? Int
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    })
}
nonUniqueElements(array1: arrayOne, array2: arrayTwo)
```

Comment: Glad I could help. I have also updated my answer with a more functional solution using higher order functions, have a look.

Comment: is there a difference in time complexity between those two solutions

Comment: No, both are linear (I am not 100% about the init of `NSCountedSet` though), but since you wrote in your question you wanted to write a solution using higher-order functions, I thought I'd show you one.

Comment: In case of someone wanting the same solution, it may be interesting to point out that values inside array1 need to be unique (same for values inside array2), or it doesn't satisfy "The function should return an array of integers that are in both arrays" from the author's question.

Comment: @Larme you are correct, the `NSCountedSet` solution only returns 1 element even if it occured several times in one of the original arrays. However, looking for non-unique elements doesn't really make sense in my opinion if one of the two arrays have repeating elements. As for the first solution, I didn't change the logic of finding the elements, only corrected the indexing error.